# How to make a number invalid

Tags: java

Create a new program called minusSentinel2.

Prompt the user to enter whole numbers between 1 and 100. Allow the user to enter as many numbers as desired.

If an invalid number is entered, print "Invalid entry." Prompt the user again until a valid number is entered.

Once -1 is entered, the program stops and prints the largest number entered with the text "The largest number entered is: "

I am having some trouble on the "Invalid entry." part. When I type a number greater than 100, "Invalid entry." does not get printed. How do I fix this? Thank you!

```
import java.util.*;
public class minusSentinel2
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1-100 (type -1 to quit):");
        int number = console.nextInt();
        int max = number;
        if (number < 1 && number > 100)//chekcs if value is valid
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry.");
            System.out.println("Enter a number between 1-100 (type -1 to quit).");
            console.next();
        }
        while (number != -1)
        {
            number = console.nextInt();
            if (number > max)
            {
                max = number;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("The largest number entered is: " + max);
    }
}
```

Comment: `number < 1 && number > 100` a number cannot be both less than 1 **and** bigger than 100. But it can be less than 1 **or** bigger than 100.

Comment: You need to kearn about boolean operators and reread your code.

Comment: Change && to ||

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I suggest you to don't copy and paste what we ask you to do, and just reformulates with only necessary parts for us.

For your issue, this condition is wrong:

```java
if (number < 1 && number > 100)
```

It correspond to "lower than 1 and bigger than 100".

So, instead of `&&` (and) operator, use `||` (or) operator like that :

```java
if (number < 1 || number > 100) {
   // it's not valid because lower than 1 or greater than 100
}
```

Finally, what you are doing seems to have another issue.
If you enter an invalid number, it will ask again only one time, and not same the new value. So, I suggest you to use while loop like that :

```java
int number = 0;
while(number < 1 || number > 100) {
    number = console.nextInt();
    if (number < 1 || number > 100) {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry.");
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1-100 (type -1 to quit).");
    }
}
int max = number;
```

To conclude, this is the full code:

```java
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in); // create scanner
int number = 0; // create new variable that will be used outside of while loop
while (number < 1 || number > 100) { // while the number isn't valid
    System.out.println("Enter a number between 1-100 (type -1 to quit):");
    number = console.nextInt(); // wait for user input
    if (number == -1) { // stop program
        console.close();
        return;
    } else if (number < 1 || number > 100) { // number invalid
        System.out.println("Invalid entry.");
    }
}

System.out.println("Now enter all number that you want. End with -1.");

int max = number; // create new max value
while (number != -1) {
    number = console.nextInt();
    if (number < 1 || number > 100) { // number invalid
        System.out.println("Invalid entry.");
    } else if (number > max) { // if number is upper than current one
        max = number;
        // here you can do something like that:
        // System.out.println("New max value: " + max);
    } else {
        // the value is value but not upper than current one, so we can write:
        // System.out.println("This value isn't upper to " + max);
    }
}
System.out.print("The largest number entered is: " + max);
console.close();
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Now the problem is that when I type 100, it would print "Invalid entry." and when I type 101, the program would continue. The maximum number would also be 101. If I paste your last suggestion into the while (number ! = -1) loop, then the largest number would not be printed. I cannot put the largest number text into the loop either. What do I do? Thank you!

Comment: You don't have to change the while (number != 1) loop. I was talking about create a new one. I will edit my post to post the full method code. Also, I don't understand what it should do with 100 and 101. It's just the condition that you have to change ?

Comment: Your solution looks really legit, but as you probably guessed.. I am a newb to coding. I only reached up to chapter 5 of this book, so I did not learn console.close().

Comment: `console.close()` is because Scanner is a resource, so it have to be closed (such as file reader for example)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, but my teacher would probably mark me off for putting that.

Comment: You can remove it if you want, or just tell it that you see documentation that say you should write it. As you want. And maybe he just want that it works, and for me it's the most important: a program with comment that do what we ask it to do